# Cannot select / move any labels with label movement tools

Tags: qgis, labeling, attribute-table, spatialite

I'm working within a Spatialite database.

I have within my attribute fields Created X, Y, and Rotation columns.

Originally I could select a label using the "change label" tool.

Once the data defined field types were assigned, My label movement tools appeared but I am unable to actually select any labels and move them.

Layer editing is enabled.

How do I actually move the labels, What is wrong?? From what I can tell from videos, Clicking it and "using the tool" should be enough, but as it is they are un-selectable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QGiS will not let you manipulate data defined fields or manually move labels if you are applying a rotation to the canvas.